# What's the best way to display new divs whenever a radio button is selected?

Tags: javascript

```
<div id="q1">
    <p>1. are you a human?</p>
    <ul class="answers">
        <input type="radio" name="q1" value="a" id="q1a"><label for="q1a">Male</label><br/>
        <input type="radio" name="q1" value="b" id="q1b"><label for="q1b">Female</label><br/>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="q2" style="display: none;">
    <p>2.what's your favorite color out of these listed</p>
    <ul class="answers">
        <input type="radio" name="q2" value="a" id="q2a"><label for="q2a">Pink</label><br/>
        <input type="radio" name="q2" value="b" id="q2b"><label for="q2b">Blue</label><br/>  
        <input type="radio" name="q2" value="c" id="q2c"><label for="q2c">Greem</label><br/>

    </ul>
</div>

      document.getElementById('q1a').onclick = function() {
            document.getElementById("q2").style.display = "block";
    }

      document.getElementById('q1b').onclick = function() {
            document.getElementById("q2").style.display = "block";
    }

      document.getElementById('q2a').onclick = function() {
            document.getElementById("q3").style.display = "block";
    }

      document.getElementById('q2b').onclick = function() {
            document.getElementById("q3").style.display = "block";
    }
      document.getElementById('q2c').onclick = function() {
            document.getElementById("q3").style.display = "block";
    }
```

So right now i'm basically checking to see if the user is checking a radio button inside of their divs and if they button is checked then the next div will be displayed.

However, this method seems kind of inefficient to me but I can't really think of a better way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a data attribute to declare what the next question is and then query that to set visibility. Something like:

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target.dataset.next) {
    document.getElementById(e.target.dataset.next).classList.add('visible');
  }
});
```

```css
.question {
  display: none;
}

.question.visible {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="q1">
    <p>1. are you a human?</p>
    <ul class="answers">
        <input type="radio" name="q1" value="a" id="q1a" data-next="q2"><label for="q1a">Male</label><br/>
        <input type="radio" name="q1" value="b" id="q1b" data-next="q2"><label for="q1b">Female</label><br/>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="q2" class="question">
    <p>2.what's your favorite color out of these listed</p>
    <ul class="answers">
        <input type="radio" name="q2" value="a" id="q2a"><label for="q2a">Pink</label><br/>
        <input type="radio" name="q2" value="b" id="q2b"><label for="q2b">Blue</label><br/>  
        <input type="radio" name="q2" value="c" id="q2c"><label for="q2c">Greem</label><br/>

    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can target the input elements by their "name" then with the radio name array, you can write some function like this one;

```
        function radioValue(radioName){
            var radioArray = document.getElementsByName(radioName);
            var i = 0;
            while(i < radioArray.length){
                if(radioArray[i].checked){
                return radioArray[i].value;
                break;
                }
            i++;
            }
        }
```

This function takes the name of the input[radio] elements and checks one by one if they are "checked" then returns the checked inputs' value.

You can use it as for your radio series;

```
        document.addEventListener('click', function(){ 
        //console.log(radioValue("radioName"));
        document.getElementById("div-"+radioValue("radioName")).display = "block";
        });
```

Read more about getElementsByName: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementsbyname.asp